# Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.2.8: UnresolvableModelException: Failure to transfer com.sun.xml.ws:bundles:pom

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, soap-client

I am following example from http://memorynotfound.com/deploy-jaxws-application-tomcat-example/. I just imported this project (as Maven) into work-space, but I see following error coming:-

```
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
        ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
    com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.2.8: UnresolvableModelException: Failure to transfer com.sun.xml.ws:bundles:pom:2.2.8 from 
    http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has 
elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
    com.sun.xml.ws:bundles:pom:2.2.8 from/to central 
(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/ws/bundles/2.2.8/bundles-
    2.2.8.pom   pom.xml /jax-ws-tomcat-example  line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

I am really exhausted with in solving the issue, please help/guide.

Answer (score 0):

The error read `connection timed out` so your maven got problems to connect to the url: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/ws/bundles/2.2.8/bundles-2.2.8.pom

Try it in your browser. It may be a network problem.